# Revit Python Shell / Revit Python Wrapper - get Element name by id

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell

I'm trying to get the name of an element by way the ID using Revit python wrapper in Revit python shell but I'm having issues. I am typically able to do it using c# but rpw is new to me.

I try:
`doc.GetElement(2161305).name` or `doc.GetElement(2161305).Name`

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected Reference, got int
```

I've looked a bit through the docs and watched some of the videos but haven't found anything that has covered this. I'm sure its easy, I'm just not not finding the answer.

Any help / direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Got to answer my own question again.

```
>>> from rpw import db
>>> element = db.Element(SomeElement)
>>> element = db.Element.from_id(ElementId)
>>> element = db.Element.from_int(Integer) # this one worked for me
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the integer to an `ElementId`. The `GetElement` has three overloads. None of them takes an `int`, so you need to cast it to clarify which one is intended. Please read the [`GetElement` documentation](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/8760be74-50fd-6809-aec6-3cb168d03ea5.htm).